# comicbook-like material that looks like one of matcaps

Tags: materials

how would you get the material that looks like black and white matcap. the last position on the matcaps "menu". the one that look like a comic book.
[image]

Comment: ...but i'm not really able figure out from that link how to make a black contour around objects like i wanted. there must be somthing with mapping from a camera view, but i'm to fresh for that.

Comment: Please edit your question showing what have you achieved so far and describing exactly why the linked question answer doesn't satisfy your needs. It describes how to to build a shader in each render engine that looks exactly like the choosen matcap.

Comment: i don't know how image texture, used in cycles engine, should look like to give the contour effect. in the link there is image texture node but i have no idea what image is used in it. 
so far i achieve nothing and that's why I asked.

Comment: You should use the exact image that makes the matcap itself https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/release/datafiles/matcaps/. The one you mentioned is the last one, n°24

Comment: thanks. this is close. with configuration from the link it doesn't give a contour on every side but i think it's a matter of tweaking it a bit. we'll see.